# How to add close bracket and close tag for react code mirror

Tags: javascript, reactjs, codemirror, react-codemirror2

I'm using react-codemirror2 in a react project. I want to add features like auto bracket close and auto tag close. There is a npm package called @codemirror/closebrackets but I can't find any documentation to do that.

```
        <ControlledEditor
            onBeforeChange={handleChange}
            value={value}
            className="code-mirror-wrapper"
            options={{
                linerWrapping: true,
                lint: true,
                mode: language,
                theme: 'material',
                lineNumbers: true
            }}
        />
```

This is my react component.
Specify if there is a way to do without additional packages like @codemirror/closebrackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `autoCloseBrackets: true` to your options and it'll work fine. [From the doc](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#config):

> Defines an option autoCloseBrackets that will auto-close brackets and
> quotes when typed.

```
import 'codemirror/addon/edit/closebrackets'

// other parts of the code//

<ControlledEditor
            onBeforeChange={handleChange}
            value={value}
            className="code-mirror-wrapper"
            options={{
                linerWrapping: true,
                lint: true,
                mode: language,
                theme: 'material',
                lineNumbers: true,
                autoCloseBrackets: true,
            }}
        />
```

Comment: That { autoCloseBrackets: true } worked. But I had to import 'codemirror/addon/edit/closebrackets'. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
This really works:

    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
    <title>CodeMirror</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel=stylesheet href="https://CodeMirror.net/doc/docs.css">
    <script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/hint/anyword-hint.js" id="anyword"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://CodeMirror.net/lib/codemirror.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/hint/show-hint.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/dialog/dialog.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/search/matchesonscrollbar.css">
    <script src="https://CodeMirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
    <script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/edit/closetag.js"></script>
    <script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/hint/show-hint.js"></script>
    <script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/hint/sql-hint.js"></script>
     <script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/mode/loadmode.js"></script>
    <script src="https://CodeMirror.net/mode/meta.js"></script>
    <script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/hint/xml-hint.js"></script>
    <script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/hint/html-hint.js"></script>
    <script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/search/jump-to-line.js"></script>
    <script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/hint/javascript-hint.js"></script>
    <script src="https://CodeMirror.net/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
    <script src="https://CodeMirror.net/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://CodeMirror.net/mode/css/css.js"></script>
    <script src="https://CodeMirror.net/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>
    <script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/dialog/dialog.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/search/searchcursor.js"></script>
    <script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/search/jump-to-line.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/search/search.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/scroll/annotatescrollbar.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://CodeMirror.net/addon/search/matchesonscrollbar.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="editor"></div>
<button onclick="closeBrackets()">Close Brackets</button>
    <script>
        function closeBrackets() {
            
            myCodeMirror.execCommand("closeBrackets");
        }
    </script>
    <script>
       var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(
       document.getElementById('editor'), {
          lineNumbers: true,
          autoCloseBrackets: true,
       });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this question is about `react-codemirror`